# Compare two dates in Elixir

Tags: date, datetime, elixir

Lets' assume that I have two dates (A and B) retrieved by

```
:calendar.universal_time(), e.g. {{2016, 5, 5}, {13, 17, 29}}
```

I need to determine if date A is greater than date B by 30 days (or more) or not.

How can I do it in Elixir?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:calendar.time_to_gregorian_days`.

```
iex(1)> {date, time} = {{2016, 5, 5}, {13, 17, 29}}
{{2016, 5, 5}, {13, 17, 29}}
iex(2)> :calendar.date_to_gregorian_days(date)
736454
```

Do it for both dates and subtract the values and check if the value is greater than 30.

Comment: I don't think this will work if the datetimes are > 30 days but < 31 days apart as the difference of days according to `:calendar.date_to_gregorian_days` will still be 30.

Comment: In that case, there is `date_to_gregorian_seconds`.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `:calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1` on both datetimes, subtract, and compare the result to `30 * 24 * 60 * 60` (the number of seconds in 30 days):

```
defmodule A do
  def thirty_days_apart(low, high) do
    min = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    (:calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(high) -
     :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(low)) >= min
  end
end

IO.inspect A.thirty_days_apart({{2000, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{2000, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
IO.inspect A.thirty_days_apart({{2000, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{2000, 3, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})
```

prints

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html):

```
a = :calendar.universal_time() |> Timex.DateTime.from_erl
b = {{2016, 4, 5}, {13, 17, 29}} |> Timex.DateTime.from_erl
if Timex.Comparable.diff( a, b, :days ) > 30 do
    # ...
end
```